# Tell Rails application to load/use the gems in the vendor rather than the default (/usr/local/)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, bundler

i have `vendorized` my apps gems in `vendor` and want my application to use those stored at `/vendor` but every time i start the application,it loads from `/usr/local` inspite having `bundle install --path /vendor`.So i cant figure out that is it possible to achieve what i want and make the application use the gems in vendor rather than going out of my apps directory.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ruby gemset you can acheive this,

```
rvm --create use $RUBY_VERSION@$GEMSET
rvm gemset list
```

You can find more details [here](https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics)